# Represent user input in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, system-design

How do I represent user input (for example, some information needed to create a new account) in a sequence diagram?

Comment: That depends on what details you need to create the account.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your sequence diagram has two lifelines, one for the user and one for your system or a component thereof. You will then have messages between the lifelines representing the interaction between both parties. User input could then be modeled as a message from the user lifeline to the system lifeline.

Each `Message` can have `arguments` (an ordered list of `ValueSpecifications`) and a `signature` which can refer to either an `Operation` or a `Signal`. The arguments of the message should match (in order) with the `parameters` or `attributes` of the referred signature. See the [UML spec](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML) for details on the highlighted technical terms.

In your example, there could be a "login" operation with parameters "username" and "password". In the sequence diagram you could then have a message with `messageSort = synchCall`, its signature referring to the "login" operation and its arguments a list of value specifications like e.g. `[LiteralString("johndoe"), LiteralString("TopSecret123")]`.